# Using PrimitiveBatch::DrawIndexed with ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed?

Tags: c++, graphics, game-engine, directx-11, directxtk

I'm creating a game engine and I'm at the point where I would want to draw wireframe shapes for debugging (colliders, triggers, raycasts, etc.). I was previously using meshes with a wireframe rasterizer state, but now I want to migrate the system over to [DirectXTK's example using their PrimitiveBatch class](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DebugDraw) so I can draw rays.

However, I am running into a problem when I call the batch's DrawIndexed() method, where everything I draw that frame, including objects from an ID3D11DeviceContext's DrawIndexed(), becomes wireframe.

[Here's what the scene is supposed to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Mhf.jpg)

[Here's what it looks like after activating the debug drawing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFl7q.jpg)

My debug drawing method:

```
void Renderer::DrawDebugShapes(ID3D11DeviceContext* context, Camera* camera, float deltaTime)
{
    if (debugObjs[0].size() < 1 && debugObjs[1].size() < 1 && debugObjs[2].size() < 1
        && debugObjs[3].size() < 1)
        return;

    db_effect->SetView(XMLoadFloat4x4(&camera->GetViewMatrix()));
    db_effect->SetProjection(XMLoadFloat4x4(&camera->GetProjectionMatrix()));

    context->OMSetBlendState(db_states->Opaque(), nullptr, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    context->OMSetDepthStencilState(db_states->DepthNone(), 0);
    context->RSSetState(db_states->CullNone());

    db_effect->Apply(context);

    context->IASetInputLayout(db_inputLayout.Get());

    db_batch->Begin();

    //Loop through all debug objs
    //0 = cubes, 1 = spheres, 2 = cylinders, 3 = rays
    for (short i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (debugObjs[i].size() > 0)
        {
            for (auto iter = debugObjs[i].end() - 1; iter > debugObjs[i].begin(); iter--)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        DrawShape(db_batch.get(), iter->world);
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        //Draw sphere
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //Draw capsule
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //Draw rays
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                if (iter->type == DebugDrawType::ForDuration)
                    iter->duration -= deltaTime;

                //Erase objs that need to be
                if (iter->type == DebugDrawType::SingleFrame ||
                    (iter->type == DebugDrawType::ForDuration && iter->duration <= 0))
                    iter = debugObjs[i].erase(iter);
            }
        }
    }

    db_batch->End();
    context->RSSetState(0);
    context->OMSetDepthStencilState(0, 0);
    context->OMSetBlendState(0, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    context->IASetInputLayout(0);
}
```

The DrawShape() call in case 0 can be commented out to remove the problem. My normal rendering is basic mesh forward rendering with a call to context->DrawIndexed() for each object and swapChain->Present(0,0) once everything (including debug shapes) are drawn. I've tried moving the debug drawing to after the swap chain, but that did not fix it.

DrawShape() just sends a world matrix to a function that draws cubes using the primitive batch [(from the DirectXTK wiki)](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DebugDraw):

```
inline void XM_CALLCONV DrawCube(PrimitiveBatch<VertexPositionColor>* batch,
    CXMMATRIX matWorld,
    FXMVECTOR color)
{
    static const XMVECTORF32 s_verts[8] =
    {
        { -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 0.f },
        {  1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 0.f },
        {  1.f, -1.f,  1.f, 0.f },
        { -1.f, -1.f,  1.f, 0.f },
        { -1.f,  1.f, -1.f, 0.f },
        {  1.f,  1.f, -1.f, 0.f },
        {  1.f,  1.f,  1.f, 0.f },
        { -1.f,  1.f,  1.f, 0.f }
    };

    static const WORD s_indices[] =
    {
        0, 1,
        1, 2,
        2, 3,
        3, 0,
        4, 5,
        5, 6,
        6, 7,
        7, 4,
        0, 4,
        1, 5,
        2, 6,
        3, 7
    };

    VertexPositionColor verts[8];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        XMVECTOR v = XMVector3Transform(s_verts[i], matWorld);
        XMStoreFloat3(&verts[i].position, v);
        XMStoreFloat4(&verts[i].color, color);
    }

    batch->DrawIndexed(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINELIST, s_indices, _countof(s_indices), verts, 8);
}
```

I've also tried resetting states after debug drawing is finished to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use **RenderDoc** to take frame capture and check GPU state for your draw calls to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINELIST` draws lines, not triangles. If you want triangles, use `D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST`.

Comment: Some more info: I had to set the topology back to `D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST` using `context->IASetPrimitiveTopology()` since the batch switches it to LINELIST

Comment: It set it to line list because you told it to: ``batch->DrawIndexed(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINELIST, s_indices, _countof(s_indices), verts, 8);``